# Why are analytical methods the most effective for studying prime numbers?

Tags: analysis, prime-numbers

As a first-year undergraduate student, I've done some extra reading about what we currently know about prime numbers as well as how we have come to this knowledge.

The proof of infinite primes by Euclid is strikingly elegant and simple. It relies on an intuitive construction and gives a strong sense of why there should be infinite primes. I've looked at Erdos's proof of Bertrand's postulate, since it was one of the only works on primes written in the last century that was accessible to me. I've also checked out some proof outlines of the prime number theorem as well as Terrence Tao's blog where he documents the most recent breakthroughs in the primes. I've also read about Vinogradov's work in using analytic number theory to prove that every sufficiently large odd number can be expressed as the sum of 3 prime numbers.

I might lack the math terminology to describe exactly what I mean here, but Euclid's proof is more akin to what I would see in my linear algebra class, whereas the recent work that seems to be giving us great results about primes seem to be more analytical in nature, i.e. more like what I'd see in my calculus and analysis class. From what I've seen, and correct me if I'm wrong here, but the recent work includes lots of bounds and estimates that are carefully chosen to work for the purpose of showing something to be true. What I say next might be a stretch, but it almost feels like the analytical proofs are "invented" in that there's a feeling of them being expressly crafted by ingeniously picking certain numbers and expressions often with error terms to show what we want to show, whereas Euclid's proof feels "discovered" as it seems to be an unalienable part of the reason *why* there are infinite primes.

My question is how come analytical methods have been so effective in making progress with prime numbers as opposed to treating the primes as, say, a dynamical system or something else? Are there other promising approaches that have produced results of a similar caliber? Do you expect that the answers to the twin prime and Goldbach conjectures will come out of analytical methods? And do you believe that the simplest possible proofs of conjectures of this level of complexity would have to be expressly crafted with estimates, bounds and error terms or do you believe there exists an intuitive and direct proof for these conjectures similar to Euclid's proof of infinite primes?

Comment: There *is* also [algebraic number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory).

Comment: The analytical approach is also quite natural (and not invented) because of the way the zeta function is associated with primes. You should also study about partition function where Ramanujan, Hardy, Rademacher used analytic tools quite effectively. There also the connection is very natural.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into these

Comment: +1 for @NoahSchweber for mention of algebraic number theory. That adds quite another dimension to number theory. As we go higher up in math education all the different branches of mathematics turn out to have surprising connections and applications and that makes the whole thing so beautiful.